# Create Intellisense database from the command line?

Tags: c++, command-line, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, nightly-build

#### The Question

Is it possible to build the Intellisense database for a solution (C++) at the command line?

#### The Context

I work on a fairly large C++ codebase. The code takes a while to compile so I set up a local nightly automated build that I can grab any time I want to start a new task. I would like to create the Intellisense database for the solutions of the codebase during this nightly build. We are using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19sf6kk3.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4sf02ac.aspx) maybe you can do something like: `devenv "X:\solution.sln" /command "Project.RescanSolution"`?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, I get the following message when I try to run this command in VS2013: Command "Project.RescanSolution" is not available.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to run the command without a solution opened :)  I can actually run the command now. I'll play around with this.The other problem with this approach is that it opens the IDE. I was hoping for a solution that wouldn't open any IDEs.

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out for this?...I would also like to be able to do this

Comment: No, I never figured out a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/55234adf-d086-4599-aacd-740ddfdabba7/how-to-create-the-intellisense-database-sdf-from-the-command-line?forum=vsx), it is (sadly) not possible:

> It is not possible to create this file without running VS, it is not a
>   scenario the team designed/planned for.
>
> Ryan